# How can I define animations for views using auto layout without relying on tons of constraint references and boilerplate code?

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiview, autolayout

Before the switch to auto layout, applying animations to a view was easy - you'd just change the frame in `UIView.layoutWithDuration:`. When constraints come into the picture, things get more complicated. The most common method of animating a view that uses auto layout is to keep a reference to the constraint(s) you want to change, then set the constant value, but this is very difficult to design around, and can affect other views if their constraints depend on the position of the view you want to animate.

There must be a better way to do this. I'd love to be able to do something like `view.translateFrom(direction: .left, distance: 30, duration: 0.3, delay: 0)`.

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately you will want to use constraints to achieve simple animations. The overriding reason for this is -

"**Choosing any other way is simply swimming against the stream**"

If you don't want to 'litter' your classes with @IBOutlets for the constraints you wish to animate then you can in most cases obtain a reference to a pertinent constraint in code:

**Handy extension**

```
import UIKit

extension UIView {
  func constraint(attribute: NSLayoutAttribute) -> NSLayoutConstraint? {
    var constraint : NSLayoutConstraint? = .none

    for potentialCenterXConstraint in self.constraints {
      if potentialCenterXConstraint.firstAttribute == attribute {
        constraint = potentialCenterXConstraint
        break
      }
    }

    return constraint
  }
}
```

**client code use**

```
if let centerXConstraint = someView.constraint(attribute: .centerX) {

  // Do something funky with centerXConstraint
}
```

Comment: It's nice to cut down on constraint references, but modifying constraint constants won't work for the reasons I listed. What if you need change to a totally different layout, or just want to change the position of one view without affecting a bunch of others? What I'm looking for here is a way to use the auto layout placement as the "finished" position when animations are done, then have the flexibility to define various animations that end up at that position.

Comment: If you don't want to affect other views when you adjust a constraint then you should look to constrain your views in a way that each view is constrained "uniquely" and not utterly dependent on other views. In simple layouts (all views can become complex). Try where possible to constrain each view to it's superview...

Comment: If i'm just going to use arbitrary offsets relative to the superview, what-is-the-point-of-autolayout? I appreciate you wanting to help, but I asked the question this way for a reason. Modifying constraints is not the solution for me. I am looking for another way.

Comment: I refer you to my earlier comment - Choosing any other way is simply swimming against the stream - that's why it feels awkward - you can of course keep looking for the other simpler way - I expect that will be frustrating. Trust me every developer has looked for a simpler way and ultimately they choose the way that works, is documented, is desirable in that it's current best practice. How many more points do you want? It enables true resizing.... It enables much more than simple offsets such as multiple offsets, stretching and relative sizes.....

Comment: "It's bad but that's what apple currently supports" is a really bad argument. If everyone followed that thinking, you'd be stupidly rewriting dozens of lines of boilerplate code in ever controller you need to avoid a keyboard. Someone decided Apple's way wasn't good enough, and now we have libraries like IQKeyboardManager. I already explained that constraints are not good enough. They outright prevent you from doing anything beyond a simple translation or stretch. If that's all you've got just move on, I'm not marking this as the answer.

Comment: It's obviously not all there is to the answer. There are 5 (F.I.V.E) points in the comment alone. Good luck in your search